# converting std::string back to cv::Mat which was generated with std::stringstream << cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, stringstream, mat

I'm saving calibration-data for stereo-vision instead the given YAML data-structure from opencv in a special data-format which allow me more flexibility.

Because of that I'm using a little hack to convert the cv::Mat into a std::string:

```
cv::Mat mat;
// some code
std::stringstream sstrMat;
sstrMat << mat;
saveFoo(sstrMat.str()); // something like this to save the matrix
```

as output I become from `sstrMat.str()` all data which I need:

```
[2316.74172937253, 0, 418.0432610206069;
  0, 2316.74172937253, 253.5597342849773;
  0, 0, 1]
```

My problem is the reverse operation of that: converting this std::string back to a cv::Mat.

I have tried code like that:

```
cv::Mat mat;
std::stringstream sstrStr;
sstrStr << getFoo() // something like this to get the saved matrix

sstrStr >> mat;  // idea-1: generate compile error
mat << sstrStr;  // idea-2: does also generate compile error
```

all try of me failed, so I would ask you if you know a method of opencv to convert that string back, or whether I write my own method to do that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the old C interface gives you what you need using load/save or read/write with CvMat, even though the doc is quite cryptic about it

Answer (score 2):

Did you implement the `operator<<(std::ostream&, const Mat&)` yourself ? If so, you obviously have to do the reverse operation yourself too, if you want it.

From your output I guess the type of the matrix was `CV_64F` with 3 channels. Be sure to remember the size of your matrix, and check the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat).

You can create your matrix with these specifications, and fill it with values while reading your stream. There are multiple examples of stream reading on the internet, but in your case that's quite easy. Ignore the characters you don't need (`[ ] , ;`) with `std::istream::read` into a dummy buffer, and use the `operator>>(std::istream&, double)` to get your values back.

What's cool about it is that you can iterate through `cv::Mat`s like you would on a standard library container. So if you're using C++11 it could look like this (not tested):

```
int size[2] = {x, y}; // matrix cols and rows
cv::Mat mat(3, size, CV_F64); // 3-dimensional matrix

for(auto& elem : mat)
{
    cv::Vec3d new_elem; // a 3D vector with double values
    // read your 3 doubles into new_elem
    // ...

    elem = new_elem; // assign the new value to the matrix element
}
```

Again, I did not use OpenCV extensively so refer to the documentation to check everything is correct.